# Should the practicality of a tag be discussed before its creation?

Tags: discussion

I have recently added a few tags to better accommodate some of my questions about a medieval empire, and have added the 'empire-building' tag. I have added a few others also.

**Should the creation of a new tag be discussed on Meta before hand, or is it okay to create an appropriate tag if you know it is not a synonym of others?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's OK to create new tags with out discussion, generally.  However, you should think about it, make sure something else doesn't already cover it and if you think it helps go for it.  If it dies or doesn't take off, we can always remove it.

One last thought though, if you think it is a questionable tag, feel free to bring it up here.  Many have, including me and you will definitely get an opinion.

Comment: "An" opinion? Pessimist. :-)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling :) or two or ten...

Comment: Something like that, yes. (That said, I think it's a great thing that we have an active community also here on Meta.)

Answer (score 4):

Like bowlturner said, there is, *generally* speaking, no need to get any sort of pre-approval on tags. If you think it will be useful, add it and see if it takes off. That's what [the *create tags* privilege](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) is all about; at a certain amount of reputation, you are considered to know the ways of the site well enough to recognize when a new tag might be more appropriate than any existing tag.

However, do be careful about **meta tags.** Those are tags that don't directly help categorize what the question is asking about. Meta tags should *probably* be discussed on meta beforehand, allowing time for a clear community opinion if perhaps not consensus to form, and should be added very sparingly.